# DAX while loop or commands to create table with rolling data 6 months back

Tags: loops, for-loop, dax

I have to calculate the Performance based on the time taken to reach target from his joining month. Now to get the target I have to get 6 month data into 1 data point. So let's we start at June 2016. we need to get all people who joined from June,May,April,March,Feb,jan 2016 data into June 2016 point. Similarly in July 2016 point will carry data from July,June,May,April,March,Feb 2016 data. This is so that there is no breakages of data at any point in my graph and I get a smooth line.

**Org Table**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDSdd.png)

```
EmpNO   JoinMonth   MonthsTken
 M12      June'16        4
 E34      June'16     3
 N56      Jan'16      2
 G89      May'16      5
 N02      April'16    3
 J90      March'16    2
 K89      Feb'16      1
 H78      Dec'15      6
 J89      Nov'15      2
K56       Oct'15      1
```

I need to get a table in the following manner. This table to be generated automatically to get values on the new months which will be plotted on the x axis. Ideally a person who joins in Feb'16 will seen in Feb'16,Marc'16,Apr;16,May'16,June'16 and July'16

```
+--------+--------------+-------------+----------+
| EmpNO  |  JoinMonth   | MonthsTken  | NewMonth |
+--------+--------------+-------------+----------+
|  M12   |    June'16   |     4       | June'16  |
|  E34   |    June'16   |     3       | June'16  |
|  N56   |    Jan'16    |     2       | June'16  |
|  G89   |    May'16    |     5       | June'16  |
|  N02   |    April'16  |     3       | June'16  |
|  J90   |    March'16  |     2       | June'16  |
|  K89   |    Feb'16    |     1       | June'16  |
|        |              |             |          |
|  N56   |    Jan'16    |     2       | May'16   |
|  G89   |    May'16    |     5       | May'16   |
|  N02   |    April'16  |     3       | May'16   |
|  J90   |    March'16  |     2       | May'16   |
|  K89   |    Feb'16    |     1       | May'16   |
|  H78   |    Dec'15    |     6       | May'16   |
|        |              |             |          |
|  N56   |    Jan'16    |     2       | Apr'16   |
|  N02   |    April'16  |     3       | Apr'16   |
|  J90   |    March'16  |     2       | Apr'16   |
|  K89   |    Feb'16    |     1       | Apr'16   |
|  H78   |    Dec'15    |     6       | Apr'16   |
|  J89   |    Nov'15    |     2       |  Apr'16  |
+--------+--------------+-------------+----------+
```

Comment: Show your data in tabular form and what are your expected results

Answer (score 1):

First i must say that I haven't tested it yet. The concept is really simple (but we need a date type column for JoinMonth). Generate (table1, table2) Returns the crossjoin of the first table with these results. The second table expression will be evaluated for each row in the first table. In first table we take all date, then for every row we create set of data and at last, we can FILTER the result

```
NewTable =
VAR BaseCalendar =
    VALUE(Table[JoinMonth])
RETURN
FILTER(
    GENERATE (
        BaseCalendar,
         SUMMARIZE (Table,
            "EmpNO", Table[EmpNO],
            "JoinMonth__", Table[JoinMonth],
            "MonthsTken", Table[MonthsTken]
        )
    )
    , [JoinMonth__] >= [JoinMonth] && DATEADD ([JoinMonth], 6, MONTH) <= [JoinMonth__]
    )
```

HERE some more info how to use GENERATE:
https://youtu.be/AieQMS6rGvM